# 500- Internal Service Error- with eQSL

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

So I am trying to implement [this interface](http://www.eqsl.cc/qslcard/ImportADIF.txt) for the eQSL Real Time api in my app, and I keep getting a error 500, with a "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed". I'm using a function to assist me in writing to the form, which can be found on [Git Hub](https://github.com/kd7uiy/trusted-qsl/blob/master/library/src/com/kd7uiy/trustedQsl/MultipartUtility.java). I've used the library before, and it works, just not with the eQSL api. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
multipart = new MultipartUtility(
        "http://www.eqsl.cc/qslcard/ImportADIF.cfm", "UTF-8");

multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible )");
multipart.addHeaderField("Accept","identity");
multipart.addFormField("EQSL_USER", mUserName);
multipart.addFormField("EQSL_PSWD", mPassword);

multipart.addFilePartOutputStream("Filename", "HamFinder_"
        + mCallSign + ".adi", new OutputStreamer() {
    @Override
    public void writeStream(OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            //Writes some output to out, I've done this way before, no problem.
        }  finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
});
List<String> response = multipart.finish();
```

I keep getting the following error back:

```
05-10 23:28:01.108: W/System.err(2456): java.io.IOException: Server returned non-OK status: 500, message Internal Server Error
05-10 23:28:01.120: W/System.err(2456):     at com.kd7uiy.trustedQsl.MultipartUtility.finish(MultipartUtility.java:182)
05-10 23:28:01.120: W/System.err(2456):     at com.kd7uiy.hamfinder.EqslUploader.writeToEqsl(EqslUploader.java:129)
05-10 23:28:01.120: W/System.err(2456):     at com.kd7uiy.hamfinder.EqslUploader.uploadQso(EqslUploader.java:72)
05-10 23:28:01.124: W/System.err(2456):     at com.kd7uiy.hamfinder.ElectronicQslManager$CommitToService.doInBackground(ElectronicQslManager.java:38)
05-10 23:28:01.124: W/System.err(2456):     at com.kd7uiy.hamfinder.ElectronicQslManager$CommitToService.doInBackground(ElectronicQslManager.java:1)
05-10 23:28:01.124: W/System.err(2456):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-10 23:28:01.124: W/System.err(2456):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-10 23:28:01.124: W/System.err(2456):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-10 23:28:01.124: W/System.err(2456):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-10 23:28:01.124: W/System.err(2456):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-10 23:28:01.124: W/System.err(2456):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

And some of the HTML code is:

```
05-10 23:28:01.108: I/System.out(2456):   <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
05-10 23:28:01.108: I/System.out(2456):   <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To whomever voted to close stating there isn't enough information, I'd love to know what else to include. I've posted most of the code, the stack trace, documentation for the api, and the key parts of the HTML Error log, I'm not sure what else I can include...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my problem is that there were two Agent fields, `multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible )");` and one added by default in `MultiPart()`. Removing one fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the server-side logs.  If you can't, then report this to the people who maintain the site.

A 500 error means that the server is (in some sense) broken.

---

Having said that, the "Accept identity" stuff is suspicious.

```
    multipart.addHeaderField("Accept","identity");
```

An HTTP Accept header is supposed to be used by the client to tell the server what kind of response it can deal with.  The header value is supposed to be a well-formed media type; e.g. "text/html" or "image/png" or "application/octet-stream".  By supplying a garbage value, you may be tickling a bug in the server's handling of Accept headers.

Reference: [HTTP 1.1 Specification: Section 14.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1)

---

**UPDATE**

In a comment you refer to a bug report that you claim supports the use of "Accept" to stop the server sending compressed response bodies.  In fact, the bug report recommends that you use "Accept-encoding".  That is a DIFFERENT header to the one you are using.

So even if the actual cause of the 500 error is different, your use of "Accept" is incorrect, and is unlikely to achieve the end you are attempting to achieve.  (The chances are that the server would not default to sending compressed responses anyway.)

Comment: I used the "Accept Identity" to try and get around Android's GZIP compression by default, but I get the same error without it. I don't have access to the server logs, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "Accept Identity" is bogus. Where does it say that that should work?

Comment: See my update.  That is "Accept-encoding", not "Accept".